# Вернуть результат в переменную

Tags: c#

Имеется следующий фрагмент кода, пожалуйста подскажите - каким образом результат можно вернуть в строковую переменную?

```
     try
        {
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(adress, 500);
            System.Net.IPAddress var = pingReply.Address;
            Console.WriteLine(pingReply.Status);
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine(adress + " - offline");
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: `return pingReply.Status.ToString()?`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int TimeOut = 1000;
Ping ping = new Ping();
PingReply state = ping.Send(IP, TimeOut);
string Ping_reply = state.Status.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try
    {
        System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping ping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
        System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(adress, 500);
        System.Net.IPAddress var = pingReply.Address;
        string answer = pingreply.status.ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine(adress + " - offline");
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
```